# Rerender child after parent's setState

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a `Stage` in my application which contains different sets of data for each.

What I want to do is if I change my stage, that my child component refreshes with data from said stage.

[image]

I have this stage selection on the top of every page, in my `App.jsx` component.
This stage is handled by the state through Redux

```
....
changeStage: function (stageId) {
    this.props.setStage(this.getStageById(stageId));
},
....
var mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
return {
       setStage: function (data) { dispatch(stageService.setStage(data)); }
    }
};
module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Now in my secondary (child - but deep down) component I have following:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextprops, nextstate) {
    console.log("stage id in this component: " + this.state.stageId);
    console.log("stage id in nextstate: " + nextstate.stageId);
    console.log("stage id from the redux store: "+ this.props.stage.id)

    return true;
},
....
var mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        stage: state.stage
    };
}
```

but `nextstate` doesn't contain the updated stage but rather the previous stage, which makes sense.
The `state.stageId` also contains the previous - also still makes sense.
but the `this.props.stage.id` I expected to contain the **newly** selected stage but it doesn't.

It actually contains the **previous** stage so that means this gets called before the state is updated or is in process of updating the state.

So anyway my question, how can I get the **new** stage selected?
I do not want to pass the stage object down to all my children because that would make it not readable at all anymore and would be sloppy in my opinion.
Anyone have any idea?

The

Comment: Did you try with nextprops.stage.id instead of current this.props.stage.id ?

Comment: That did work, please post this as answer so I can accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use nextprops.stage.id instead of this.props.stage.id to get the nextprops passed to your component.